# python webscraping with BeautifulSoup Problem

Tags: python-3.x

Im trying to scrape the box score table from https://www.nascar.com/stats/2021/1/box-score

my code is not working if someone could take a look and point me in right direction.

```
`import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = ('https://www.nascar.com/stats/2021/1/box-score')
response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
stats = soup.find_all('table', class_ = "stats-box-score-table-driver")
stats
for row in stats.find_all('tr'):
    for cell in row.find_all('td'):
        print(cell.text)
```

Comment: what does not working mean? is it not giving you the output you desire or not running?

Comment: Also, the table is filled by javascript after the page is loaded so it is hard to scrape that as such. If you look into that, you will quickly realize that the script calls the api `https://cf.nascar.com/cacher/2021/1/points-feed.json` which fetches all data you seem to need in json format.

Comment: Are you saying the page cant be scraped?

Comment: not with `requests` and `bs4`, either check the api i posted or use `selenium`